# i want to print this methods result in View without grid just by using html

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Please get me out of this. I want to print this methods result in View without grid just by using html.

```
public JsonResult GetDeficiency([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    List<Walkthru> deficiency = new List<Walkthru>();
    Walkthru wt = new Walkthru();
    wt.deficiency = "Incorrect faucet installed";
    wt.image = "";
    deficiency.Add(wt);

    wt = new Walkthru();
    wt.deficiency = "Very low water pressure";
    wt.image = "";
    deficiency.Add(wt);

    return Json(deficiency.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean in a table? Why not return a partial result that renders the data. If you want JSON to update an existing table, then `return Json(deficiency, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` and access the collections properties in the AJAX success function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution what I can offer is through Knokcout JS. lets say you have a controller action which will actually give you set of records -

```
 public JsonResult GetDeficiency()
 {
     List<Walkthru> deficiency = new List<Walkthru>();
     Walkthru wt = new Walkthru();
     wt.deficiency = "Incorrect faucet installed";
     wt.image = "";
     deficiency.Add(wt);

     wt = new Walkthru();
     wt.deficiency = "Very low water pressure";
     wt.image = "";
     deficiency.Add(wt);

     return Json(deficiency, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

Then you html and JQuery can be -

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.js"></script>    

<div class='table table-bordered' data-bind= "foreach: records">
     <div>
          <div data-bind="text: deficiency"></div>
          <div data-bind="text: image"></div>
      </div>
</div>

<script>
    function Model() {
        var self = this;
        self.records = ko.observableArray([]);

        $.getJSON("/home/GetDeficiency", function (data) {
            self.records(data);
        })
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new Model());
</script>
```

When you run the code, you can see all the records displayed in the divs as items.

Comment: actually the return statement is like this                      return Json(deficiency.ToDataSourceResult(request),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);